# sharing a static class with a DLL in C# without passing a reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll, .net-assembly

VS2012 for desktop .net framework 4.5  normal windows forms applications, not WPF
Hello, I tried to search for an answer, but I'm not sure of the correct terminology. I've managed to break my code, and can't understand what I've done wrong. (i didn't think i had changed anything, but ...)

I have a solution which contains 2 projects. The first project is an executable program, and the second is a DLL, which is loaded at run time and used by the first project.

the first project contains a form, and a static class with public static strings in the same namespace. (and some other unconnected classes). specifically:

```
namespace project1_namespace
{
    static class settings
    {
        public static string some_words = "some words in a string";
    }

    class dll_callback{
         //.. some public methods here
    }

    dll_callback dllcallback; // instance is initialised in the code (not shown)
    Form form; 

    public partial class frm_splash : Form
    {
        private void frm_splash_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
           // this function actually loads the DLL, ensuring its the last step
           //... some error checking code removed for brevity

               Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\dllpath\project2.dll");
               Type type_init = assembly.GetType("project2_class");
               object init = Activator.CreateInstance(type_init, form, dllcallback);           

           //... some error checking code removed for brevity
        }// end method
    }// end form class
}// end namespace
```

when the form is closing, the method shown above is called which calls the second projects class project2_class constructor.

in project 2, the DLL, there is:

```
namespace project2_namespace
{
// how did i get this working to reference "settings" class from project 1??
    public class project2_class
    {
        public project2_class(project2_namespace.Form1 form_ref, object callback)
        {
            settings.some_words = "the words have changed";
            //... some more stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Now, i was experimenting with some code in an entirely different part of project2, and VS2012 suddenly started refusing to compile stating:
error CS0103: The name 'settings' does not exist in the current context

the standard solution to this appears to be to add a reference to project2, but that would create circular dependencies because project 1 calls 2 as a DLL.

I really honestly don't think i had changed anything relevant to this, but also clearly I have.
looking at it, i cant see how project 2 would have access to a class in project 1 without a reference, but the list of arguments to the project2_class constructor doesn't include one, and I am absolutely positive that it hasn't changed (and I cant change it for backwards compatibility reasons). 
would really appreciate help with this, as its been a lot of work to get this working.

---

as a side note, I've definitely learned my lesson about not using source control. and not making "how this works" comments instead of "what this does" comments.

Answer (score 1):

may dynamic help you? You can not get the setting string at complie time.

Comment: Thanks Marty, what is dynamic?  I know that I can't like that, but i have been getting the string. (i have the built program and dll to prove it)